# keep alive spring websocket connection

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, keep-alive

I have an spring boot application with the messaging module dependency. I have the following scenario: The client connects, it sends an identifier (so as to associate the identifier with the session) [I have a custom component to hold these sessions] BUT, for some reason, Spring Boot removes the session adter sometime... I thought it would be enough to have an scheduling task to send dummy messages to the client every X time... but no... so the question would be: How could I keep alive the connection (backend) and avoid the removal ?...